# "Arbitrary" context free grammars?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Long time admirer first time inquirer :)

I'm working on a program which derives a deterministic finite-state automata from a context-free grammar, and the paper I have been assigned which explains how to do this keeps referring to "arbitrary probabilistic context-free grammars" but never defines the meaning of "arbitrary" in relation to PCFGs. I assume they mean "any old PCFG" but then why not just say "any PCFG"?

The term also turns up in several Wikipedia entries. At the top of [the CFG page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) there is a reference to arbitrariness in relation to CFGs on  ("clauses can be nested inside clauses arbitrarily deeply"), but doesn't make clear why someone would refer to a PCFG or subset of PCFGs as arbitrary.

In case anyone is curious, the paper is *Parsing and Hypergraphs* by Klein and Manning (2001); I've also been reading two other papers by them related to this one (*An Agenda-Based Chart Parser for Arbitrary Probabilistic Context-Free Grammars* and *Empirical Bounds, Theoretical Models, and the Penn Treebank*) which use the term extensively but never explain it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Arbitrary" means "any" like you are thinking.  It emphasizes that they assume no special conditions on the PCFG.  As for why, if you look at a sentence like "a tabular parsing framework for arbitrary PCFGs", "arbitrary" is a better word choice than "any".

Comment: Thanks! Also noticed that Google will autocomplete to "arbitrary set" so presumably it's a term used frequently in set theory.